# How-to rewrite a binary file or modfiy its control flow graph

Tags: reverse-engineering, binaryfiles, control-flow

Essentially I want to rewrite a binary file to perform additional tasks regarding its actual tasks.
Regarding binary rewriting the process seems to be following:

1. Create a Control Flow Graph from an existing binary
2. Create a Code Snippet with the desired changes in an appropriate format
3. Create a binary file from the modified CFG

I came across a couple of tools, which either won't compile on my ubuntu 12.04, are not available for download or I can not find a decent tutorial / howto on how to hot patch / rewrite a binary. Those tools are:

ParseAPI, Code-Surfer/x86, EEL, LEEL, Jakstab, DynInst, Diablo + Lancet

To be more precise I want to analyze a given binary for its most frequently used functions and change it in such a way that before executing these functions, a given set of instructions are performed.
These instructions comprise of loading an array of stored bytes, reading a byte at a certain position and comparing it with a pre-defined value.
I want to make sure that the binary definitely executes these instructions during every trial.

There are 2 alternative approaches I came across which basically alter standard c functions (like `memcpy()`, `strcpy()`, `printf()`, etc.) since I assume these functions to be part of the binary with high probability:

1. `LD_PRELOAD`: Define my own libraries and let them get loaded before the ordinary ones
2. Compile the binary (of sourcecode is given) with own versions of the standard functions using something like `gcc -fno-builtin -o strcpy strcpy.c`

Drawback of this approach is that eventhough I subsitute standard c functions they do not necessarily have to get called, hence my instruction will not get executed neither.

Do you guys have experience regarding binary rewriting or do your have clues for accomplishing this rather exotic task?

Best regards!

Comment: Dyninst should definitely work. If you have any questions, just email bugs@dyninst.org. We respond pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

BAP and Dyninst would help you. You may use BAP (http://bap.ece.cmu.edu/) to get the control flow graph of a binary. It have a very easy to use utility  to create control flow graph from binaries. And you may use dyninst to instrument binaries and perform your desired operations. BAP absolutely runs on ubuntu12.04. Dyninst might not compile on 12.04 (there might be some linking problems). A simple walk around is that you do instrumentation on 10.04 and run the rewritten binaries on 12.04. Both tools are free.